# How can I set the Spinner menu to DropDown instaed of dialog style?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, spinner

I created a Spinner style file, because I'd like to have a nice looking spinner.
Now if I click on the spinner i don't get anymore the default dropdown menu, but a dialog, to select an item from the spinner. How can I change it back to dropdown?

XML:

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:background="@drawable/radiosection">
>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView2"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="@string/headerkernlochrechner"
>         tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
>         tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="162dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
>
>
>     <Spinner
>         android:id="@+id/steigungsspinner"
>         style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
>         android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
>         android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

The Spinner Style:

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_spinner</item>
</style>
```

And the Spinner Style Background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>

        <layer-list>

            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

                    <stroke android:width="0.33dp" android:color="#0fb1fa" />

                    <corners android:radius="0dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:right="5dp">

                <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

            </item>

        </layer-list>

    </item>

</selector>
```

Thank you for help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I find a answer:
I had to add in the XML of the spinner the line:

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

Now it works!